# MongoDb - find by NumberLong operation

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, azure-cosmosdb, isodate

I have following example model data in my mongo db:

```
    timelineStart {

    "_id" : ObjectId("5982cd5f2801e5d848g368hw"),
    "startDate": NumberLong("1501747729035"),
    "table": {
        "_id" : ObjectId("3fhyi9801e5d848g368hw"),
        "timeWindow": 20
    }
}
```

and I wanted to query all timelineStarts where `state is equal to NEW` and `startDate - number of hours in timeWindow` are lower than current date.

I have prepared following query:

```
db.timelineStart.find({$and: [
    { "status": { $eq: "NEW" }},
    { $where: "var timelineStart = this.startDate;timelineStart.setHours(timelineStart.getHours() - this.table.timeWindow);  timelineStart <= new ISODate()" }
    ]
});
```

Which works fine, but I would like to avoid variables initialization inside of where clause. If I run this query on Azure Cosmos it is not working, because `request is malformed`, so it seems that syntax is wrong for Cosmos.

Do you know how can I rewrite this query to avoid variables inside of it?

Comment: The simplest way is to calculate `endDate` once when you save the document.

Comment: Odds are on that `$where` is not supported. Nor should you be using it at all. There is absolutely no reason why you could not "do the math" external to the query and simply select the "range" between. You should be using basic `$gte` and `$lt` operators, which would actually perform a lot better as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn Could you please show me example? I do not get quite what you mean

Comment: I have tried this query, but it does not return me correct data: `db.timelineStart.aggregate([ { $match: { "startDate": { $lt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() + "$table.timeWindow" * 3600000) } } }, { $match: { "status": "NEW" } } ])`